# React Navigation TypeScript Error - Argument type not assignable to parameter type

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm encountering an issue with TypeScript and React Navigation in my React Native app. I have set up the navigation using `@react-navigation/native-stack` and `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`. I'm facing a type error when using navigation.navigate() in one of my components.

**Problem:**

In the ./src/screens/Profile/Profile.tsx file, I'm trying to navigate to the "EditProfile" screen using navigation.navigate("EditProfile"). However, TypeScript is throwing an error, and I'm having difficulty understanding and resolving it.

**Error Message:**

```
No overload matches this call.
Argument of type '["EditProfile"]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[screen: "HomeStackNavigator"] | [screen: "HomeStackNavigator", params: undefined] | [screen: "Profile"] | [screen: "Profile", params: undefined]'.
Type '["EditProfile"]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "HomeStackNavigator"] | [screen: "Profile"]'.
Type '["EditProfile"]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "Profile"]'.
Type '"EditProfile"' is not assignable to type '"Profile"'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(options: { key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: "HomeStackNavigator"; key?: string | undefined; params: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { ...; }): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: "HomeStackNavigator"; key?: string | undefined; params: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { ...; }'. ts(2769)
```

**Is this TypeScript error related to the fact that I have nested navigators in my application? I'm using both stack and bottom tab navigators, and I'm wondering if this nested structure is contributing to the type error.**

**Here are code snippets:**

```
// ./src/screens/Profile/Profile.tsx

import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, Pressable } from "react-native";

import styles from "./styles";
import user from "../../../assets/data/user/user.json";
import { ProfileScreenProps } from "../../navigation/types";

const Profile = ({ navigation }: ProfileScreenProps) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.avatar}>
        <Image source={{ uri: user.avatar }} />
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("EditProfile");
          }}
        >
          <Ionicons name="settings-sharp" style={styles.settingsIcon} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.nameText}>{user.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.usernameText}>{user.username}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.joinedText}>{user.joined}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

```
// ./src/navigation/index.tsx

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import React from "react";

import BottomTabNavigator from "./BottomTabNavigator";
import { RootStackNavigatorParamList } from "./types";
import EditProfile from "../screens/EditProfile";
import Lesson from "../screens/Lesson";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackNavigatorParamList>();

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="BottomTabNavigator">
        <Stack.Screen name="BottomTabNavigator" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Lesson" component={Lesson} />
        <Stack.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditProfile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

```
// ./src/navigation/BottomTabNavigator.tsx

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import React from "react";

import HomeStackNavigator from "./HomeStackNavigator";
import { BottomTabNavigatorParamList } from "./types";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabNavigatorParamList>();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeStackNavigator"
        component={HomeStackNavigator}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

```
// ./src/navigation/HomeStackNavigator.tsx

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import React from "react";

import { HomeStackNavigatorParamList } from "./types";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import HomeSettings from "../screens/HomeSettings";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<HomeStackNavigatorParamList>();

const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeSettings" component={HomeSettings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeStackNavigator;
```

```
// ./src/navigation/types.ts

import { BottomTabScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NativeStackNavigationProp, NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

export type RootStackNavigatorParamList = {
  BottomTabNavigator: undefined;
  Lesson: undefined;
  EditProfile: undefined;
};

export type BottomTabNavigatorParamList = {
  HomeStackNavigator: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};

export type ProfileScreenProps = BottomTabScreenProps<BottomTabNavigatorParamList, "Profile">;

export type HomeStackNavigatorParamList = {
  Home: { selectedSectionId: string } | undefined;
  HomeSettings: undefined;
};

export type HomeScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<HomeStackNavigatorParamList, "Home">;

export type HomeSettingsNavigationProp = NativeStackNavigationProp<HomeStackNavigatorParamList, "HomeSettings">;
```

**Question:**

1. Could this error be related to having nested navigators (stack and bottom tab navigators) in my application? If so, how should I handle navigation within nested navigators in TypeScript?
2. How can I resolve this error and successfully navigate to the "EditProfile" screen?
3. Are there any changes I need to make to my types or navigation setup?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.